# If one sits in an airplane does one weigh slightly less due to the centrifugal acceleration of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Our weight on Earth is a bit less (specially at the equator) due to axial spin of the Earth. But is this effect also there when there is no direct contact with the Earth?

And would the answer be the same if the Earth didn't have any atmosphere at all, given that the airplane uses a rocket?

Answer (score 0):

As the Earth rotates you are moving in a circle.  This means that you must be accelerating towards the centre (centripetal acceleration).  Were you not accelerating towards the centre you you just continue moving in a straight line off into space not unlike mud being flung from a spinning wheel.

Centripetal acceleration can be calculated using $a_c=\frac{4\pi^2r}{T^2}$.  Using a value of one day for $T$ and the radius of the Earth for $r$ we get about $a_c=0.03\space  \mathrm{m/s^2}$.  This means that you **and your surroundings** are accelerating downwards at this rate.

If the Earth's gravitational pull were the only force acting on you it would produce an acceleration downwards of about $9.81\space \mathrm{m/s^2}$ . However, since your surroundings are all accelerating downwards at $0.03\space \mathrm{m/s^2}$the *apparent* acceleration due to gravity is reduced by $0.03\space \mathrm{m/s^2}$.

The effect you describe would still exist even if you had no direct contact with the Earth.  If the plane were flying towards the East the time it would take you to complete one revolution, $T$, would be reduced and the effect would be amplified.  If you were flying west $T$ would be increased and the effect would be decreased.  Were you flying at the same rate as the Earth was spinning (about 1600 km/h) the effect would go away.  In this situation you could consider yourself at rest with the Earth spinning beneath you.

Whether or not the Earth has an atmosphere would not make a difference though the atmosphere does provide a small buoyant force that works against gravity.

Technically the term *weight* refers to the force of the Earth's gravity acting on you which wouldn't change based on your motion.  It would be more precise to speak of your apparent weight.

Comment: But can you explain how this works? How can a 'force' works at a ('spooky') distance?

Comment: This is assuming straight and level flight. A plane that is  flying parabolic arcs (e.g., the Vomit Comet) can have apparent weight vary from zero to twice normal weight. A fighter plane subjects its pilot to even greater variations in apparent weight.

Comment: I'll edit my answer as to why the apparent weight is reduced.    By the way, do you consider all forces that act a a distance to be spooky - gravity, electrical, strong nuclear etc.?

Comment: Perhaps 'spooky' doesn't need to be emphasized. But I can understand when standing on Earth there is an effect, but at distance how can this work, or what explaniations can be used?

Comment: perhaps space dragging is involved?

Comment: @Marijn Well gravity still acts on you when you aren't touching the Earth.  There's also plenty of other forces like atmospheric forces acting on you.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask about though.